# How to get the values in django model field?

Tags: python, json, django

I want to get all the values in my country_name field in a JSON response.

Here is my models.py :

```
from django.db import models
class Countries(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.country_name)
```

and here is the view to get it :

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from .models import Countries
import json
from django.core import serializers
def AllCountries(request):
    countries = list(Countries.objects.all())
    data = serializers.serialize('json', countries)
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/json")
```

Here is the JSON response I get:

[{"pk": 1587, "model": "interApp.countries", "fields": {"country_name": "bangladesh"}}]

But I dont want the "pk" and the "model", I just want all the country names.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/serialization/#subset-of-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instead **use [`QuerySet.values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) method to get all the countries name** and then send this data in json encoded form.

```
def AllCountries(request):
    country_names = list(Countries.objects.values_list('country_name', flat=True))
    data = {'country_names': country_names}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

You can use [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) also instead of `HttpResponse`. There would be no need to do `json.dumps()` then as this will be performed by `JsonResponse` class itself.

```
def AllCountries(request):
    country_names = list(Countries.objects.values_list('country_name', flat=True))
    data = {'country_names': country_names}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try this without serializers means follow this, it is simple thing did in views.py itself..

```
data = map(lambda x:{'country_name':x.country_name},Countries.objects.all())
return HttpResponse(content=json.dumps({'data':data}),content_type="application/json")
```

Simply Replace your 3 lines with above 2 lines and you may add field what ever you want from models inside dictionary.